# Blurz Rust Library on Raspberry PI 4 Bluetooth connection with specific Device

Tags: rust, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I'm making a project on raspberry pi 4 model b based on Rust, using the [Blurz Rust Library](https://docs.rs/crate/blurz/0.4.0).

So this is my code:

```
let sessionBLE = BluetoothSession::create_session(Option::None).unwrap();
let adapter: BluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter::init(&sessionBLE).unwrap();

let discoverySessionBLE : BluetoothDiscoverySession = BluetoothDiscoverySession::create_session(&sessionBLE, adapter.get_id()).unwrap();


println!("IS DISCOVERABLE {}", adapter.is_discoverable().unwrap());
println!("IS POWERED {}", adapter.is_powered().unwrap());
println!("IS DISCOVERING {}", adapter.is_discovering().unwrap());

adapter.set_discoverable(true);

println!("start discovery");
discoverySessionBLE.start_discovery().unwrap();


thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
println!("<------------------------------------------>");
println!("IS DISCOVERABLE {}", adapter.is_discoverable().unwrap());
println!("IS POWERED {}", adapter.is_powered().unwrap());
println!("IS DISCOVERING {}", adapter.is_discovering().unwrap());
println!("device list number (count) {}", adapter.get_device_list().unwrap().len());
println!("device list {:?}", adapter.get_device_list().unwrap());


let devices = adapter.get_device_list().unwrap();

println!("Test array.: {}", adapter.get_device_list().unwrap()[1]);
let uuid = adapter.get_uuids().unwrap()[1].to_string();

println!("Connecting..");
let deviceBle : BluetoothDevice = adapter.get_first_device().unwrap();

deviceBle.connect(10000);
thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
println!("device BluetoothDevice {}", deviceBle.get_address().unwrap());
println!("device RSSI {}", deviceBle.get_rssi().unwrap());
println!("device CONNECETED {}", deviceBle.is_connected().unwrap());
println!("device GATT {:?}", deviceBle.get_gatt_services().unwrap());
```

Everything works but there's a problem, so I don't understand how to connect to specific device. This is the list found after scan:

```
["/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D4_CA_6E_F0_9E_21", "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_A0_50_FC_85_B4", "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_7D_A6_E2_28_E2_21", "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_7D_26_EF_98_8A_F4", "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_42_14_C3_01_25_25", "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_75_0C_80_CD_04_1E", "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_52_71_26_A1_52_AA", "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_40_C3_D7_65_CC_BF", "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_72_95_B8_34_82_A3", "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_6B_99_43_81_D0_31", "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_45_66_4A_20_7C_0B", "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_46_99_9C_AA_BD_36", "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_CC_52_AF_CB_49_12", "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_C4_22_C6_95_9C_1A", "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_A0_50_FC_18_46", "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_A0_50_FD_15_F4"]
```

I can't connect to a specific device, I need to connect with the third device: "7D_A6_E2_28_E2_21" but from the documentation I don't understand how to, I see there's a single method:

```
let deviceBle : BluetoothDevice = adapter.get_first_device().unwrap();
```

But it gets only the first device, what can I do to get the third device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty straightforward with [`BluetoothDevice::new`](https://docs.rs/blurz/0.4.0/blurz/bluetooth_device/struct.BluetoothDevice.html#method.new):

```
let device_3 = BluetoothDevice::new(&sessionBLE, devices[2].clone());
```